# Need a simple clarification on d3selection.DATA()

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

I have an object with 4 fields, each field holding an array with 600 datapoints.

I'd like to **plot each array on a separate d3.js graph** -- small multiples i think it's called. I'm still a little shaky on the data-binding part of it and can't seem to go from a container to multiple svg appends.

I understand this following basic example, but I think, am missing something about the nature of data-binding in d3:

```
      circleData = [[10, "rgb(246, 239, 247)"], [15, "rgb(189,201,225)"],

      [20, "rgb(103,169,207)"], [25, "rgb(28,144,153)"], [30, "rgb(1,108,89)"]];

      //Select the div element
      selectExample = d3.select("#data_example2");

      //We'll select all the circle from within the selected <div> element
      selectExample.selectAll("circle")
      .data(circleData)//<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("cx", function(d){return d[0]*14})
      .attr("cy", 50)
      .attr("r", function(d){return d[0]})
      .style("fill", function(d){return d[1]});
```

Basically what i would do right now is just replace `circleData` in `.data(circleData)` with my own data object and keep appending axes and labels below it, basically expecting that for every of 4 fields(subarrays), a graph will pop up. .(i.e.

```
svgSelection.
.data(my_multi-field_array_object)
.enter()
.append("g")
... //continue with the individual plot's code
```

This, unsurprisingly, does not work. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Renesting the *object of arrays* to be an *array of objects* did the trick. 
Not sure why that wouldn't be covered by the function.